# HTML Purifier equivalent for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Has anyone encountered an equivalent to HTMLPurifier for Rails apps?  Essentially I need to clean up often terribly formed HTML generated by users before saving to the DB.

http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: Wonder if you have run into anything since posting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [sanitize method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize).

```
sanitize(html)
```

There is also a [Sanitize gem](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/).

```
Sanitize.clean(html)
```

I tend to prefer the Sanitize gem because it can be used as a before_save filter in your models instead of having to use the sanitize method in each of your views.

Comment: Mikhail - thanks.  The sanitize method is limited for what I need but the gem just might work using its transformers.  I often have lots of invalid html submitted (pasted from word or pages) so I need a lot of cleaning up.  Sanitize is a bit of a club - but with some work on the transformers it might work.  Has anyone encountered anything that can specifically address copy and paste from MS Word?